# Is there such a thing as a WordPress 'dashboard'-like MediaWiki GUI front-end/interface?

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

I've recently looked at installing a wiki engine, in order to provide - as with most wikis - a user-editable repository of information. I've looked at three specific engines:

- [DokuWiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki)
- [TikiWiki](http://info.tikiwiki.org/tiki-index.php)
- [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki)

My users' preference tends towards MediaWiki (presumably due to familiarity and some semblance of brand awareness), which is fine with me. The downside of this wiki engine is that its administrative/configuration options seem to be ... dated. A colleague described it as *php and pray*, which seems a fair assessment.

So I'm left wondering: is there a plug-in, or another resource, that allows for a simple dashboard-style configuration editor (à la WordPress, for example)?

Comment: seems a bit off-topic.

Comment: Maybe change the subject to be less subjective.

Comment: @neo, I wasn't entirely sure. But it seems border-line relevant to both SU and WA (and entirely off-topic to SF and SO); so it seemed a worthwhile question, *if only* for the purpose of helping to **define what Web-apps is not**. That said, I half-agree, but it *seemed* a better fit here than SU.

Comment: @Stefan Lasiewski, *attempted* =)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [Extension:Configuration](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aConfiguration). May note that the MediaWiki developers actually want the configuration to be a php file to be more flexible.

Comment: A valid point (and +1), but Wordpress allows that same flexibility to those who want to dig into the php, while presenting an easy-to-use interface to those that want simplicity/ease-of-use and, essentially, don't want to dig into the php.